# C# and CS-Script: variables not in context

Tags: c#, cs-script

[C# newbie]

Hi. This is a test of **CS-Script** 3.28.7, **to add scripting to C#**.
I need to implement very simple functions that will be later read from a cfg file.

I went through the docs, but **didn't find the way to read external classes and static vars**. I get for both `values` and `rnd` the message `the name XXX is not available in this context`.

What am I forgetting?

```
using System;
using CSScriptLibrary;

namespace EmbedCS
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExecuteTest();
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void ExecuteTest()
        {
            bool result;
            var scriptFunction = CSScript.CreateFunc<bool>(@"
                bool func() {
                    int a = rnd.Next(10);
                    int b = rnd.Next(10);
                    return values[a] > values[b];
                }
            ");

            result = (bool)scriptFunction();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work

```
using System;
using CSScriptLibrary;

namespace EmbedCS
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        public static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExecuteTest();
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void ExecuteTest()
        {
            bool result;
            var scriptFunction = CSScript.CreateFunc<bool>(@"
                bool func() {
                    int a = EmbedCS.Program.rnd.Next(10);
                    int b = EmbedCS.Program.rnd.Next(10);
                    return EmbedCS.Program.values[a] > EmbedCS.Program.values[b];
                }
            ");

            result = (bool)scriptFunction();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Remeber that, in C# everything is so implicit.

your `func()` is not a member of `Program`. So they can't recognize fields inside the `Program`.

Some dynamic languages have binding context(such as ruby's `binding`) in language level, so libraries can do black magic stuffs. but not in C#.

Comment: If you want to make code clean, try this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

Comment: I gave a look at the link but don't understand where to place the `using static` it in my code. I would use it inside the script, as a first line (`using static EmbedCS.Program.values;`) but cannot find the correct syntax.